# Pegar valor de 2 colunas em GridView para realizar calculo

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema simples de Entrada/Saida de usuários em um ambiente  e possuo um Grid com alguns dados e dentre eles 2 campos do tipo DateTime, sendo eles Entrada e Saída.

Preciso pegar os valores destes campos de TODAS AS LINHAS do meu Grid e então realizar um cálculo para saber a permanencia do usuário no local (permanencia = saida - entrada), entretanto não estou conseguindo capturar os dados destas duas colunas linha por linha.

A coluna 4 é a coluna de Entrada e a coluna 6 de Saida.

Obs: Todo o código se encontra dentro de um botão.

Segue meu código:

```
private void btCalcPermanencia_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime ent = new DateTime();
    DateTime saida = new DateTime();
    TimeSpan permanencia = new TimeSpan();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
    {
        ent = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[4].Value);
        saida = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[6].Value);
        permanencia = saida - ent;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(permanencia.ToString(), "Permanencia");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu erro está acontecendo porque está pegando os valores apenas das linhas selecionadas, troque `SelectedRows` por `Rows`

Obs. Dentro do Loop, o comando `dataGridView1.Columns.Add(permanencia.ToString(), "Permanencia");`
 irá adicionar uma nova coluna para cada linha que for percorrida, Crie a coluna antes do loop, e apenas coloque o Value dela:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("colunaPermanencia", "Permanencia");
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ent = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
    saida = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
    permanencia = saida - ent;
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["colunaPermanencia"].Value = permanencia.ToString();
}
```

E tire o `-1` do `for` porque se não, a última linha não será percorrida

Comment: Funcionou. Muito Obrigado. Agradeço mesmo...

Comment: Bem vindo à comunidade, marque como resposta por favor =] é o V logo abaixo da avaliação da resposta